Logic App upload big file to Blob fails with cannot write more bytes to the buffer
Hi have a HTTP request that downloads a document from an API. This works for documents smaller than the default 105 MB but obviously hits a snag with bigger documents. It is set to chunked but it looks like despite that setting, the 105 MB is hardcoded?
I've set the environment variables: 
yet this doesn't seem to have made a difference. I'm still getting the bad request error.

Anyone out there managed to get past this issue?

Instead of updating environment variables, the hosts.json file should be updated.
Follow these steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/edit-app-settings-host-settings?tabs=azure-portal#azure-portal---hostjson
In my test, I also was getting this error initially:

When I added the Runtime.Backend.HttpOperation.MaxContentSize setting to the hosts.json file as follows –
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle.Workflows",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  },
   "extensions": {
      "workflow": {
         "settings": {
            "Runtime.Backend.HttpOperation.MaxContentSize": "314572800"
         }
      }
   }
}

– the error has gone:

Action outputs:

